# How can I control the Terminal in the current space with AppleScript?

Tags: terminal, macos, applescript, command-line, spaces

Working on building a Handler that passes the terminal window then calls the ID for a script I've run into mixed results and I'm curious if there is a cleaner way to get `window 1`

**The handler:**

```
on termHandler()
    set activeTerminal to ""
    if application "Terminal" is running then
        tell application "Terminal"
            if not (exists window 1) and not busy of window 1 then
                activate
                tell application "Terminal" to do script "echo snow" in window 1
            else
                tell application "Terminal" to do script "date" in window 1
                set activeTerminal to window 1
                return activeTerminal
            end if
            do script "echo foo"
            activate
            set activeTerminal to window 1
            return activeTerminal
        end tell
    else
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            do script "echo bar" in window 1
            set activeTerminal to window 1
            return activeTerminal
        end tell
    end if
end termHandler
```

Everything I've read and researched:

- [Applescript to open a NEW terminal window in current space](https://superuser.com/questions/195633/applescript-to-open-a-new-terminal-window-in-current-space)
- [Open terminal via AppleScript](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170602/open-terminal-via-applescript)
- [Applescript to open specific Terminal Style Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7807962/applescript-to-open-specific-terminal-style-windows)
- [Script opens two terminal windows](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/224925/script-opens-two-terminal-windows)
- [Sending commands and strings to Terminal.app with Applescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1870270/sending-commands-and-strings-to-terminal-app-with-applescript)

Suggests that AppleScript and Terminal do not get along.  My current OS is Sierra I'm writing this in but other boxes I have run Yosemite which would use this script. My end goal here is to identify a Terminal window in that particular space and fire some `do script` but I seem to be having an issue doing so.  Is there an easier way to identify if the Terminal is running, not create a new window and if it is running return the `window 1` as a variable so I can pass it `do script`?

Comment: This comment doesn't address any issue with **Spaces**, however, here's an issue I see right off the bat. If **Terminal** is _open_ and without a `window`, then `if not (exists window 1) and not busy of window 1 then` will fail and you have not coded an _error handler_ for that scenario. Another issue I see is, if **Terminal** is _open_ and without a `window`, then `activate` brings **Terminal** forward but doesn't create a new `window`. Continued in next comment...

Comment: You either have to programmatically click the **Terminal** _Dock Tile_ on the **Dock**, or use **System Events** to **⌘N** or tell **Terminal** to `reopen` to then have `window 1` exist in this scenario. Just some points to think about.

Comment: why not leave that as an answer?  If there is a mistake I'm all for a better approach to the end goal.

Comment: I didn't post it as an answer because it doesn't address issues you are having with Spaces.

Answer (score -1):

Do you need to actually have it input into a terminal window or is that just the way that you found it to work? I am not sure if you are aware of this or not but you can run shell scripts directly from an AppleScript by using this "do shell script" command. As an example:

```
do shell script "echo snow"
```